# How to know if the input value equals something

Tags: jquery, if-statement, input, authentication

So for school i'm making a login system for a website (without a database), so I have a input field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="gebruikersnaam" placeholder="Username">
```

And a button to login like this:

```
 <input type="submit" name="login" id="loginknop2" class="signIn loginhide signin-submit" value="Login">
```

now when the username the user has put in equals "timo" and the button is clicked, so I have this code:

```
var gebruikersnaam = $("#gebruikersnaam").val(); 

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loginknop2").click(function(){
      if(gebruikersnaam == "timo"){
        console.log("Ja! het werkt.");
      }
      else{
        console.log("Nee! het werkt niet.");
      }
  });
});
```

but I can't get it to work, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read input value inside click handler, see below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loginknop2").click(function(){
      var gebruikersnaam = $("#gebruikersnaam").val(); 
      if(gebruikersnaam == "timo"){
        console.log("Ja! het werkt.");
      }
      else{
        console.log("Nee! het werkt niet.");
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

move

```
var gebruikersnaam = $("#gebruikersnaam").val();
```

inside the callback.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#loginknop2").click(function(){

      var gebruikersnaam = $("#gebruikersnaam").val(); // <-- here

      if(gebruikersnaam == "timo"){
        console.log("Ja! het werkt.");
      }
      else{
        console.log("Nee! het werkt niet.");
      }
  });
});
```

because you should read the input value after the click

Answer (score 0):

Take the value of `textbox` in `click` handler otherwise you might have empty string in it when event is triggered. You are not event getting the value of textbox in document.ready which may cause selected to get failed in getting the object with id `gebruikersnaam`

```
 $("#loginknop2").click(function(){
      var gebruikersnaam = $("#gebruikersnaam").val();
      if(gebruikersnaam == "timo"){
        console.log("Ja! het werkt.");
      }
      else{
        console.log("Nee! het werkt niet.");
      }
  });
```